# tailwind: How to use arbitrary values with pseudo classes

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to change an Icon based on the pseudo class `peer-checked`.
I thought I could just `peer-checked:fa-icon`. But this does not work.
So I tried with a simple class and this also does not work.
How is it done?

```
<style>
  .my-red-background {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
<div class="bg-blue-500 hover:my-red-background">hover</div>
```

EDIT: there is way to do change the icon with tailwind, but its ugly:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden peer" />
  <div class="peer-checked:hidden">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden peer-checked:block">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i>
  </div>
  <div>Label</div>
</label>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74429397/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tailwind-layer-directive/74432943#74432943) may help you to understand how does Tailwind utilities works

Comment: You can use arbritary variants. But you might also think it will be ugly. But why your solution in the edit is ugly? What is bad about it?

Comment: Here it is what I mean by also ugly: https://play.tailwindcss.com/wic3R00SVI You can do a combination of those. but I think you second example is pretty good.

Comment: @RicardoSilva I think its ugly because you have to keep the icons siblings of checkbox to make `peer-` work. So you have to repeat several classes. If I could just swap only the relevant classes (like the icon) on `checked:` it would be way cleaner. 
Funky solution, didn't know that was possible. Can you point me to the documentation of whats going on there?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the link tag like this:

```css
.mydiv i {
  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.mydiv i:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="mydiv">
  <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: sure, that works, but I wonder if I can do it with tailwind (goal being able to do sth like:
`fa-icon hover:fa-icononhover`

Comment: Hope this is what you need

Comment: no sorry. I want a non-tailwind class with hover.

Comment: do you need it in pure CSS?

Comment: Yes, no JS. I've edited my question, there is the solution I'm using now.
But just `peer-checked:fa-solid` would be way better. Seems like thats not possible.